# Ansible starts EC2 instance in a terminated state

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

So I'm working on some ansible playbooks to manage EC2 instances, and here is one of them:

```
---
- name: Create linux EC2 node
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False
  roles:
    - { role: ec2, ec2_volume_size : 500 ,
        ec2_ansible_tag: { ansible_type: linux-node },
        ec2_instance_type: "m4.large" 
      }
    - { role: ec2_eip, ec2_tag: tag_ansible_type_linux_node }
```

The ec2 role is as follows:

```
- name: Create instance
  local_action:
    module: ec2
    region: "{{ ec2.region }}"
    key_name: "{{ ec2_key_name | default(ec2.credentials) }}"
    instance_tags: "{{ ec2_ansible_tag | combine( ec2.tags ) }}"
    image: "{{ ec2_image | default(ec2.image) }}"
    instance_type: "{{ ec2_instance_type | default('t2.small')}}"
    instance_profile_name: "{{ ec2.role | default('') }}"
    ebs_optimized: "{{ ec2.ebs | default(false) }}"
    group: "{{ ec2_groups | default(ec2.group_name) }}"
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ ec2_subnet | default(ec2.subnet) }}"
    assign_public_ip: "{{ ec2.public_ip | default('yes') }}"
    private_ip: "{{ ec2.private_ip | default('') }}"
    monitoring: "{{ ec2_cloudwatch | default('no')}}"
    wait: yes
    volumes:
      - device_name: /dev/sda1
        volume_type: gp2
        volume_size: "{{ ec2_volume_size | default(100) }}"
  register: ec2inst

- name: register data
  set_fact:
    ec2_create_data: "{{ec2inst}}"
```

The issue is that it starts them in terminated state, which only started to happen very recently.

The output is :

```
"msg": "wait for instances running timeout on (Timeout Time)"
```

What can lead to this happening?

Comment: Worth a look: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_InstanceStraightToTerminated.html

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov I've seen this somewhere briefly while looking up. Thank you for pointing it out, I'll research this further.

Comment: run your playbook with -vvvv (to enable
                        connection debugging) and you will find the answer why :)

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov You're totally right it's "State transition reason message
Client.VolumeLimitExceeded: Volume limit exceeded"

Comment: @Berlin that's how I got the output message, it was not very conclusive, so I've asked

Comment: Sorry I didn't know, I just tried to help.

Comment: @Berlin thanks, -vvvv helps, but sometimes it's not intuitive, since ansible is working with other tech that can have issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from the comments:

> Worth a look: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_InstanceStraightToTerminated.html
>
> You're totally right it's "State transition reason message Client.VolumeLimitExceeded: Volume limit exceeded"